# Validate Complete Flat file before import in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Have one flat source file of around 1 GB and needs to be imported to table. But before importing need to validate the complete source file (all records) before transformed into the destination table. And after importing need to validate the table and flat source file. How can it be done using SSIS ?

Basically there is flat file with the following clumns

```
Date | Item ID | Item Name | Qty | Price | Amount
```

and destination table is  tblTransactions with the following columns

```
TranID | Date | ItemID | Qty | Price | Amount
```

and lookup table for ItemMaster is

```
ItemID | ItemName
```

Before importing need to iterate through all the records in the source file and check Item Name value length is < 150. If any of the item name is not less than 150, then import should abort and after that it has to increase the ItemName column length to max size it received. New items must be inserted to the tblItemMaster

Comment: why negative ? anything wrong in the question ?

Comment: More details like, what is the validation - datatype/null values/etc. and details of the file format and your destination table structure with details of what you have done so far will help in getting answers

Comment: That is not necessary Raj, I have mentioned need to validate all rows (It could be anything), Its clear that need to validate all rows, if success then actual importing should start.

Comment: Fine. So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you want to validate the entire file before importing? First, it means that you will have to read the entire file twice: once to validate it, and once to load it. Second, if only one row is invalid then you have to stop the whole load. Third, if you increase the size of the target column dynamically then how will you use that column in later code, because the later code will not know the new data type? It would probably be easiest to load the entire file 'as is' using a `varchar(max)` column for the name, and continue processing from there.